# How to get the log traces in angular 2+?

Tags: angular, eventlog-source

Can anyone tell is there any inbuilt module or way to fetch the event traces from event viewer in angular 2+ ? Like how we use system diagnostics Eventlogs extension to fetch traces in c#.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for **NGX Logger**

"NGX Logger is a simple logging module for angular (currently supports angular 6+). It allows "pretty print" to the console, as well as allowing log messages to be POSTed to a URL for server-side logging."

You can also try **Angular2-Logger**

"A simpler Log4j inspired logger module for Angular 2. Think of it as "Log4ng" ... get it?

This is a work in progress and is not ready for production, use with care, the API can and will change."

**JSNLog** is also another options for you. You can get following flexibility using this

- You probably log server side exceptions and other events using a logging package such as Log4Net, Elmah, or NLog.

So there are many log tracer exists so depends on your requirements, you can choose whichever suit most for your projects.

Comment: Thanks I will check. But will the Ngx logger be able to communicate with the machines event viewer? Basically I don't want to log anything. I just want to fetch the logs which already available in event viewer.